# Algorithm for determining the set of pair visible edges between two concave polygons

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry

Let's say we have two concave 2d polygons(A, B), that don't intersect. The problem is to find the set of edge pairs(each pair consist of one edge from polygon A, and the edge from polygon B), that have following property: each item in pair must be visible to each other. One edge is visible to another, if there are no obstacles(in the pic there are three cases, marked with red cross, when this rule is broken) between them.

[image]

I know how to solve this problem in O(n^2) using rays and vertices of edges. But it is too slow.

Comment: Each pair of edges forms a quadrilateral.  In essence, you need to find whether any other edge intersects that quadrilateral.

Comment: The brute-force algorithm would be O(n^3): For each pair, you go through the edges again to see if that edge is obstructive.  How did you get it to O(n^2)?

Comment: This looks like a variation of the Art Gallery Problem, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Art_gallery_problem may give you some pointers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think it can be done faster than O(n^2).

See the picture below. There is a hyperbola and two polygons. The vertices of each polygon are on a branch of the hyperbola.

[image: Two polygons. One on each branch of a hyperbola.]

In this case, the edges of the two polygons are pair-wise visible (except the two edges behind). Then the resulting set will contain O(n^2) pairs of edges.

Comment: hmm. Maybe there some prepocessing could be made. Like BSP in games for removal hidden surfaces.

Comment: @innochenti That does not change the size of the output, which is the real bottleneck. But if you modify your problem/requirement/desired output, there may be faster solutions.